# VB.NET What is the best way to pass value to another form?

Tags: vb.net, parameter-passing

I have two form which uses the same connection string such as,

`Dim connStr as String = "Server = localhost; Database = tester; Uid = root; Pwd = 123"`

The code above is placed in Form1. So in my Form2, I will be using the same connection string again. Instead of copy and paste it again to every next form, what is the best way to do it?

I have tried using this code, `Public Property connString as String = "bla..bla"` for Form2. Then in Form1, I let it hold the same string like this `Form2.connString = connStr`

Is this the right way to pass value between forms? Or is there a proper/better way to do it?

Comment: A ConnectionString should be stored in the app.config (web.config) through the Properties settings of your project. Then you can read that value using _ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[keyOfYourString].ConnectionString_ Do not hard code them in your program and of course don't it pass between forms

Comment: The most common way is to abstract such things as connection strings away from the user interface. That is, you should have a seperate class (or even classes) that handles the database connection. Of that class, you could instantiate objects that know the connection string. But even in those, you wouldn't hardcode the connection - you should retrieve it from configuration (app.config or web.config for example).

Comment: Thank you @Steve! Will learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Properties, events or constructors are the best way of passing data between forms.

Comment: `Form2.connString = connStr`  you probably want to get away from using default form instances as well (the sooner, the better)

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry I dont seem to get you. Mind explaining a bit on that?

Comment: `Form2` looks to be the class name.  Form object ought to be created (`Dim f As New Form2`).  Using the default instance is allowed (in VB) as a holdover from VB6.  It will bite you sooner or later.

Comment: @Plutonix I see what you meant already. That was just an example. In my real code I uses `new`. Example `Dim f1 as Form2`, `f1 = new Form2()`, `f1.Show()`, `f1 = Nothing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to pass or call a variable from different forms is to create a module.

Open Visual Studio, click PROJECT from the menu bar > Add Module... > Select Module > OK

From there, you can declare your GLOBAL VARIABLES.

```
Module Module1
   Public connStr as String = "Server = localhost; Database = tester; Uid = root; Pwd = 123"    
End Module
```

The variable "connStr" can now be called from different forms.

From your Form1 and Form2 you can just call this GLOBAL VARIABLE as if they are your local variables.

Comment: Thanks. So how do you call it then from other forms?

Comment: You can just simply call it like how you call your local variables.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted your answer. Please update it to show full guide on how to call it too

Comment: Yes it work. But I am not really sure if this is the best way though. Because if your form has the same variable name in your module, it would get really confusing

Comment: Your connection string will not change anyway, right? So you can just allot a specific variable name for your connection then. If you're going to have multiple connections then create another variable for them.

Answer (score 0):

create constructor and pass arguments as value you want to pass between form like below

```
Sub New(ByVal s As String, i As Integer)
```